# Why does Jesus intercede or Advocate after salvation?

Tags: nature-of-god, sin, will-of-god, god-the-father, anger

In several passages, we see Christ as our advocate (1 John 2:1) or our mediator (1 Timothy 2:5).

My question is three fold:

- Why does Christ actively mediate or advocate after salvation? Does God the Father forget that we're saved?
- Also I've often heard it said that God the Father is against us and Christ is for us, so does that mean that the Father and Son have two different wills? One that hates us and the other that loves us?
- Does God the father love those whom Christ advocates for and is God the father angry at believers every time they sin?

Comment: Might help to pare down this question to 1 question. Although they're related, I think you're opening up a can of worms with just the first question.

Comment: Your main question is a good one, but you go on to ask, "I've often heard it said that God the Father is against us and Christ is for us, so does that mean that the Father and Son have two different wills?" If you look to the r.h.s. here, under 'Related', you will see that answers to this have already been given. Also, on here, it's good to identify a particular group whose answers you wish to get, so you might ask those who do not believe Mary intercedes for them.

Comment: Seems like https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/77639/how-should-we-understand-the-ongoing-nature-of-jesus-intercession-heb-725-27 is  about the same matter.

Comment: The question misunderstands the righteousness of _God_ (not the Father), and the necessity of redemption.

Comment: @bob do you want answer to this question from a Reformed/Protestant perspective?

Comment: "If God be for us (not against us!), who can be against us? He that spared not his own Son, but delivered him up for us all, how shall he not with him also freely give us all things?" So God the Father is *clearly* not against us.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I can use all the intercession I can get. :)

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the first point:

- **Why does Christ actively mediate or advocate after salvation? Does God the Father forget that we're saved?**

I'm not sure what you mean by interceding or advocating ***after*** salvation, perhaps you misunderstood that the fact **that he intercedes and advocates for us** is what ***brings* us salvation**; we are *only* saved ***because* he intercedes and advocates for us**. Or, perhaps you just meant "after" to imply pursuance, and your focus was just on why he "*intercedes* and *advocates*" which your next two points denote.

Addressing points 2-3:

- **Also I've often heard it said that God the Father is against us and Christ is for us, so does that mean that the Father and Son have two different wills? One that hates us and the other that loves us?**
- **Does God the father love those whom Christ advocates for and is God the father angry at believers every time they sin?**

The Father cannot stand wickedness and wrongdoing.

> Psalm 11:5 
> The Lord tests the righteous, but his soul hates the wicked and the
> one who loves violence.
>
> Isaiah 13:11 
> Thus I will punish the world for its evil And the wicked for their iniquity; I will also put an end to the arrogance of the proud And abase the haughtiness of the ruthless.

Yes, God hates those who do wrong, and *must* punish wrongdoing, he *thirsts* to **right what is made wrong**, and **all of us** have done **wrong** to *such an extent that **we do not comprehend***. So yes, he is angered by us, and he will **only** turn away his anger **if we turn to his Son**. And if, on top of our sins, we *reject* his Son, what do you think should be done?

> Romans 6:23 
>  For the wages of sin is death, but the free gift of God is eternal life in Christ Jesus our Lord.

The Father loves us (and *love* is not just a stronger form of *like*, but means to truly, selflessly care about what is best for someone), but he does turn to hate those who know him and learn of all his goodness, and then still choose wickedness; those who fully give in to the selfish, destructive way of life, and have no sorrow or comprehension of what they do to others, that is what *evil* is. 

And if you would like more references, [here](https://www.openbible.info/topics/god_hates_sin) are some good ones about him hating sin, and [here](https://bible.knowing-jesus.com/topics/Punishment-Of-The-The-Wicked) are some about him punishing the wicked.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks

> "Why does Jesus intercede or Advocate after salvation?"

Because Jesus is the **way** through whom all comes to be in the new kosmos - the Kingdom. He is an intermediary from humanity to the Father. We are **saved** to the extent **we abide in Christ**. To the extent we abide in Christ, we **stop sinning**.

1 John 2:1

> "My little children, I am writing these things to you so that you will
> not sin. But if anyone does sin, we have an advocate before the
> Father—Jesus Christ, the Righteous One. 2 He Himself is the atoning
> sacrifice for our sins, and not only for ours but also for the sins
> of the whole world."

John then continues at 1 John 3:5

> "But you know that Christ appeared to take away sins, and in Him there
> is no sin. 6 No one who remains in Him keeps on sinning. No one who
> continues to sin has seen Him or known Him."

The OP asks

> Why does Christ actively mediate or advocate after salvation? Does God
> the Father forget that we're saved?

One is saved **because** one abides in Christ.